# Write out what i select in my <select> list in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, select, html-select, property-binding

I want to write out the option i choose from my select list. I know that i should use change but now how i should use it. !now im just writing to get the letters in!

My ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { selectBeverage } from "../interface-beverage";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-beverage',
  templateUrl: './select-beverage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-beverage.component.css']
})
export class SelectBeverageComponent implements OnInit {


    beverages: selectBeverage[] = [
      { id: 1, drink: "Beer" },
      { id: 2, drink: "Soda" },
      { id: 3, drink: "Wine" },
      { id: 4, drink: "Water" }
    ];



  clickedBeverage(){

  }
  constructor() {

   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

My template file:

````
<select [(ngModel)]="beverages">
  <option *ngFor="let b of beverages" [value]="b.id">
    {{b.drink}}
  </option>
</select>
<br><br>
One {{selectedOption}}, coming right up! ```
````

Comment: Your array and ngModel is using same variable.

Comment: You want to print out what is selected from the dropdown?

Comment: @NicholasK Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable in the typescript file named `beverageToDisplay` and bind to that in the template within the `<select>` tag.

.ts

```
beverageToDisplay: string;
```

.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="beverageToDisplay">
  <option *ngFor="let b of beverages" >
    {{b.drink}}
  </option>
</select>

<p *ngIf="beverageToDisplay">One {{beverageToDisplay}}, coming right up!</p>
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bev) found here.

Answer (score 0):

The [(ngModel)] of the select contains the selected value, not the list of options.

.ts file:

```html
export class SelectBeverageComponent implements OnInit { 

...
// add member here
selectedOption: any; // instead of any one could use something more precise in the next step

...
}
```

Template file:

````html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"> <!-- i corrected value of ngModel, it contains the selected value -->
  <option *ngFor="let b of beverages" [value]="b.id">
    {{b.drink}}
  </option>
</select>
<br><br>
One {{selectedOption | json}}, coming right up! ```
````